# Converting short date to long date

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the following code:

```
dim currentDate as Date
currentDate = Format(wkSheet.Cells(3, i), "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")
```

Cells(3, i) is a date in short form
I'm trying to convert it to a long form so for instance 7/1/2018 would become Sunday, July 1st, 2018. How to do this? The above code is based on the "record a macro" function.

Comment: Format returns text, not a true date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format returns text, not a true date. Change the cell's number format.

```
wkSheet.Cells(3, i).NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
```

Note that date formats do not include <sup>st</sup>, <sup>nd</sup>, <sup>rd</sup>, <sup>th</sup>, etc. and your supplied date format is a forced two digit day (e.g. 01, not 1<sup>st</sup>)